# Is it possible to have 2 separate Google Voice phone numbers?

Tags: google-voice

Can I get 2 Google Voice numbers?

I have a single phone number issued by AT&T. I can sign up, but the verification process requires me to enter a phone number to link and as soon as I enter the phone number to link, the previous Google Voice number gets disconnected.

From [their official docs](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/165221?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1), it appears you can have just 1 GV number - 1 phone.

> You can link up to 6 numbers. You can't link a number that's already linked to a Google Voice number.

So is there any obvious loophole that can be used to get 2 phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR - it's possible to get more than one GV number; you can only use one at a time; here's how and why it can be useful.**

FWIW, linking a GV number to a "real" mobile number is only really needed when you to take ownership of the GV number, solely for verification purposes (it's one SMS message with a 6-digit code, just like any other MFA).

Once you have the number in your GV account, you can unlink the "real" mobile number from the GV number and they are completely separate again.  So, if you already have a GV number and really want another one, find a friend that will let you use their phone for the SMS verification code, then unlink their number right afterwards.  Viola, you have another GV number.  The caveat is that the friend can't then use their number to get their *own* GV number, so make sure they don't care.

If you have more than one GV number (so, multiple Gmail accounts), you need to link the one you want to use to your actual mobile number under **Google Voice > Settings**.  You can link/unlink as many times as you want, which means you can change which GV number is tied to your phone any time you want.  You can *NOT* link more than one GV number to your mobile number simultaneously.

This came in handy for me because I wanted to add another line to my cell phone plan, but if I didn't bring a number with me the carrier would force me into a higher plan ($35/month) for that additional line. If I brought a number with me it was only $15/month.  That's $2,400/year!  Ridiculous!  Google only charges three dollars to unlock a GV number, which allows you to port it to the carrier of your choice.  When you add the line the carrier will port it over for you.  So, there are some instances where this can be useful.

This is all true as of November, 2023.  Who knows if Google will decide to change things up someday.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only loophole would be to get a second real phone number, as each can only be linked to one GV number. This could easily be done with a "burner" phone if they're available near you, or if someone else will let you use their phone to signup, or a government ("Obama") phone.

Another VoIP number won't work because they're identifiable as being VoIP. It requires a mobile or landline number.